# PayPal REST API for chained payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

In a web application which is still being developed, we are using the Adaptive Payment SDK. The application uses the chained payment in which there is a primary receiver, which takes a percentage of the payment and then forwards the rest to secondary receiver. We are considering switching to the new Paypal REST APIs. Does it support the said use case?

Comment: Hey I was wondering if you solved the chained payments with Paypal Rest API. Currently I am using SOAP API to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal REST API doesn't support Parallel/Chained Payments. And there's no ETA for it. Hopefully someday. There seems to be quite a few requests for it.

Comment: Is this still true ?